# if is not session , redirect to login page

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I am trying to code a simple script,
I created a " ADMIN Panel "  , so if the user is admin (admin=1) then he can pass and see the link/file
If he is not (admin=0) then he should be redirected to login page , and if is not  Session['username'] he should go back to login page ,
but it seems that i have a problem with this code, in user panel it works , but in admin panel it doesn't

```
<?php

include './includes/db.php';
session_start();




// ADMIN CHECk

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND admin=1");

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);



if($count != 1) // make sure user is a admin

{
        session_start();

        session_destroy();

    header("location: login.php");

    die;

}



if(isset($_GET['act'])) 
{
    if($_GET['act'] == "logout") 
    {
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        header("location: login.php");
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: There seems to be no if( ? ) in the code supplied. Please supply the code. Also try to keep you outputted language in one language. "Hej" vs "Total Users"

Comment: oh sorry copied the wrong text :3
Take a look now ? this is adminheader.php
In the last file i included    " include'adminheader.php'; "
But didn't work

Comment: how many times you are starting session? why don't you check also password in query?

Comment: Sir i'm new to PHP ,
That's why i posted this , if I knew the solution i wouldn't ask here !

Comment: then check for session only once  this way    if (!isset($_SESSION))
  {
    session_start();
  }

// Check to see if user is already logged in
    if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
    }

Comment: 1. Donot use mysql, it's dieing (use at mysqli instead). 2. your code is prone to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing i see is that you don't declare the session first. Secondly, the mysql function is deprecated, mysqli will do what you need done. This fix should work for you. Also it would be easier to have a logout.php.

db.php

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli(host, user, pass, database);

?>
```

Then, in your page, you can run the queries like so:

```
<?php

session_start();
include './includes/db.php';

//check that the session exists
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])
{
  //the session does not exist, redirect
  header("location: login.php");
}

// ADMIN CHECk
$username = $db->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND admin='1'");

$count = $result->num_rows;



if($count != 1) // make sure user is a admin

{
    header("location: login.php");
}

?>
```

Then in logout.php, you should remember to actually unset the session variables

```
<?php
 session_start();
 //unset session variables
 unset($_SESSION['username']);
 session_destroy();
 header("location: login.php");
?>
```